# Bundle specific commits and unbundle without prerequisites

Tags: git, bundle, rebase

I have an example git repository1 with the following commits:

`Initial commit
 Commit 1
 Commit 2
 Commit 3
 Commit 4
 Commit 5
 Commit 6`

I'd like to share `commit 3` to `commit 5` to a friend. I can do this with `git bundle create`. My friend needs to have a repository from `initial commit` to `commit 2`. However, I do not want to share commits from `initial commit` to `commit 2`. Sharing the bundle would result in the following error: `Repository lacks these prerequisite commits`.

To avoid this, I can use `git rebase` then bundle the repository. However, this would modify my git repository as well, and I do not want to do that.

Is it possible to share a bundle containing commits `commit 3` to `commit 5` and that my friend does not have commits from `initial commit` to `commit 2`? My friend should have a repository similar to the following:

`Initial commit <- this is Initial commit + commit 1 + commit 2
 Commit 3
 Commit 4
 Commit 5`

Answer (score 0):

Using a shallow clone you will share the same history and commit hashes.

## Creating a shallow clone

1. Tag or place branches at the end commit

   git tag endTag Commit5Hash
2. Create a shallow clone, it's important to use the file:// syntax, otherwise you will get a full clone.

   git clone --depth 3 file:///path/to/your/repo --branch endTag newCloneRepo
3. Zip the folder and send it

## Sending more commits using git bundle

1. Create your bundle from the original repo, assuming main is the last commit to send them

   git bundle create path/to/bundle.file endTag..main
2. Pull the bundle into the newCloneRepo

   git pull path/to/bundle.file main